# faster alternative to cp -a

Tags: cp, file-copy

For a simple transfer of /home to another disk i use `cp -a` that seems to me an  extremely slow way. Should like know a more efficient way to complete the task. I have /home mounted as logical volume, but the target disk is not an LVM system

Comment: If `cp` is slow, other methods would be slow too. Unless it's not file-oriented copying

Comment: Try to diagnose your bottleneck, that depends on your particular setup. You may want to try the `noatime` mount option to reduce unnecessary writes, specially to source file system.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `tar`, `pax`, `cpio`, with something buffering.

```
(cd /home && bsdtar cf - .) |
  pv -trab -B 500M |
  (cd /dest && bsdtar xpSf -)
```

I suggest `bsdtar` instead of `tar` because at least on some Linux distributions `tar` is GNU tar which contrary to `bsdtar` (from `libarchive`) doesn't handle preserving extended attributes or ACLs or linux attributes.

`pv` will buffer up to 500M of data so can better accommodate fluctuations in reading and writing speeds on the two file systems (though in reality, you'll probably have a disk slower that the other and the OS' write back mechanism will do that buffering as well so it will probably not make much difference). Older versions of `pv` don't support `-a` (for average speed reporting), you can use `pv -B 200M` alone there.

In any case, those will not have the limitation of `cp`, that does the *reads* and the *writes* sequentially. Here we've got two `tar` working concurrently, so one can read one FS while the other one is busy waiting for the other FS to finish writing.

For ext4 and  if you're copying onto a partition that is at least as large as the source, see also [`clone2fs`](http://freecode.com/projects/clone2fs) which works like `ntfsclone`, that is copies the allocated blocks only and  sequentially, so on rotational storage is probably going to be the most efficient.

[partclone](http://partclone.org/) generalises that to a few different file systems.

Now a few things to take into consideration when cloning a file system.

Cloning would be copying all the directories, files and their contents... and everything else. Now the *everything else* varies from file system to file systems. Even if we only consider the common features of traditional Unix file systems, we have to consider:

- links: symbolic links and hard links. Sometimes, we'll have to consider what to do with absolute symlinks or  symlinks that point out of the file system/directory to clone
- last modification, access and change times: only the first two can be copied using filesystem API (cp, tar, rsync...)
- sparseness: you've got that 2TB sparse file which is a VM disk image that only takes 3GB of disk space, the rest being sparse, doing a naive copy would fill up the destination drive.

Then if you consider `ext4` and most Linux file systems, you'll have to consider:

- ACLs and other extended attributes (like the ones used for `SELinux`)
- Linux attributes like immutable or append-only flags

Not all tools support all of those, or when they do, you have to enable it explicitly like the `--sparse`, `--acls`... options of `rsync`, `tar`... And when copying onto a different filesystems, you have to consider the case where they don't support the same feature set.

You may also have to consider attributes of the file system themselves like the UUID, the reserved space for root, the fsck frequency, the journalling behavior, format of directories...

Then there are more complex file systems, where you can't really copy the data by copying files. Consider for example `zfs` or `btrfs` when you can take snapshots of subvolumes and branch them off... Those would have their own dedicated tools to copy data.

The byte to byte copy of the block device (or at least of the allocated blocks when possible) is often the safest if you want to make sure that you copy everything. But beware of the UUID clash problem, and that implies you're copying onto something larger (though you could resize a snapshot copy of the source before copying).

Comment: GNU tar has the `--acls` option, to store the ACLs into the archive. And I'd be surprised if an alien (of sorts) tool like `bsdtar` handles it better than the (essentially) native one...

Comment: @vonbrand. Your tar must have been patched for that (I think RedHat has a patch for GNU tar for ACLs), because the latest version of GNU tar doesn't support such an option. There exist a number of implementations of `tar` for Linux (`star`, `bsdtar`, `tar`), I'm not aware that GNU tar is any better than the others. The choice for GNU tools is generally more political than technical (see for instance `bash`).

Comment: Using GNU tools might be a political choice, but it is the default choice nevertheless. And as they are _much_ more popular than the alternatives, there also is more developer (and other) manpower behind them.

Comment: thanks, the next time i will use pv and tar rather then cp

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Currently GNU tar [does support `--acls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC42)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend rsync, for example:

```
rsync -av --progress --stats dest orig
```

Or, to transfer with compression:

```
rsync -avz --progress --stats dest orig
```

Comment: `rsync` is generally a lot slower than `cp` or `tar|tar`

Comment: Thanks for this information :)

but i never compared these two...

Comment: [A look at rsync performance - LWN.net](http://lwn.net/Articles/400489/)

Comment: I wouldn't trust that article too much.  I use rsync quite frequently and regular copy at 130-170 MB/sec.

Comment: `rsync` is mostly efficient is you already partially have the source data available on the destination volume because it will only transfer missing/changed data. I would not use it for a fast "first copy".